# Angular 8 update metatags on the DOM causes delay in changes in the view

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that needs to update the view after some http call.

HTML-

```
 <mat-spinner *ngIf="loading"></mat-spinner>
<span *ngIf="!loading">This is my record </span> {{record}}
```

TS-

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

ngOnInit(){
    this.loading = true;
    this.callServer():
}

callServer() {
    this.service.callServer()
        .subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.onSuccess(data);

            },
            (error) => this.onError(error)
        );
}

onSuccess(data) {
    this.loading = false;
    this.record = data;
    this.addGoogleMetaTags(this.record);
}
```

addGoogleMetaTags is a function that is responsible for adding/removing/updating meta tags in the document using the Meta service of angular.
it takes a lot of time to run and only after it finishes I can see that the loading disappears and I can see the data of my record on the screen.
I tried to trigger angular change detection after setting "this.record = data" but it did not help.
I tried to call to the google function by doing this, but it did not work either-

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => this.addGoogleMetaTags(this.record));
```

How can I make my app reflect immediately the changes without waiting for addGoogleMetaTags to end?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ngZone, adding timeout of 0 to this line solved the problem-

```
this.addGoogleMetaTags(this.record)
```